# NaN error appearing when I run my code

Tags: c++

first off this is a class assignment so i would appreciate help but just hints as i want to learn. I have to calculate final number as seen in my code but something is off with my calculation. My output reads nan which i believe is not a number. I have been trying to figure out where i am going wrong to no avail,any suggestions on how to correct this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int say;
float iten_paket[100],daxil_olan_paket[100];
float P_B[100]; // Itmis paketlerin ehtimali = P(B)
float P_S[100]; // Her bir serverin secilme ehtimali = P(Si)
float sum=0,final[100],A[100]; 
cout<<"Please enter server number => ";
cin>>say;

for(int k = 1; k<=say; k++){
    cout<<"Please enter the taken packet number for : "<<k<<" server ";
    cin>>daxil_olan_paket[k];
    cout<<"Please enter the lost packet number for : "<<k<<" server ";
    cin>>iten_paket[k];
}
// Her serverin secilmey ehtimali tapilir, P(S 1,2,3.....n)
for(int i = 1; i<=say; i++){

    P_S[i] = 1/say;
}
for(int c = 1; c<=say; c++){

    P_B[c] = iten_paket[c]/daxil_olan_paket[c];
}
for(int d = 1; d<=say; d++){

    A[d] = P_S[d]*P_B[d];
}
for(int f = 1; f<=say; f++){

    sum=sum+A[f];
}

// Bayes dusturu P(Sn|B) = P(B|Sn)*P(Sn)/P(B)

for(int a = 1; a<=say; a++){
    final[a] =(float) A[a]/sum;
    cout<<"For server "<<a<<" probability is :"<<final[a]<<endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Did you perhaps enter 0 for any `daxil_olan_paket` element? You are dividing by that.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, what did your debugger say were the parameters to the calculation that produced your `NaN`?

Comment: Please enter server number => 3
Please enter the taken packet number for : 1 server 20
Please enter the lost packet number for : 1 server 1
Please enter the taken packet number for : 2 server 30
Please enter the lost packet number for : 2 server 2
Please enter the taken packet number for : 3 server 50
Please enter the lost packet number for : 3 server 3
For server 1 probability is :nan
For server 2 probability is :nan
For server 3 probability is :nan

--------------------------------
Process exited after 14.06 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: this is what it says

Comment: No, this is not the output from your debugger. This is the output from your program, not your debugger. What did your debugger show you for the values of `A[a]` and `sum`, that were used for the division that resulted in your `NaN`? This is something that you should be able to figure out all by yourself, with your debugger's help, instead of asking on stackoverflow.com. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: I am not a developer I am just simple student. Sorry I dont know annything about debugging

Comment: Yes, NaN means not a number. It usually comes from dividing zero by zero.

Comment: But I am not dividing it to the zero

Comment: I see division in two places in the code. Chances are that one of those is the culprit.

Comment: If you're a student, then you are learning (or at least supposed to be). So.... you should _learn to debug_. ;) I have no idea what sort of development environment you're using, but start by looking for debug and break-point options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NaN` is almost always a divide-by-0 error, which it is in this case.

1. First, `int/int` evaluates to 0 since `1 < say` in:

   ```
   P_S[i] = 1/say;
   ```
2. Next, `0 * x` evaluates to 0 in:

   ```
   A[d] = P_S[d] * P_B[d];
   ```
3. Then, `0 + 0` evaluates to 0 in:

   ```
   sum = sum + A[f];
   ```
4. Finally, `x/0` evaluates to `NaN` in:

   ```
   final[a] = (float) A[a]/sum;
   ```

This is a common beginner's error. Simply do `float/int` in at the start:

```
P_S[i] = 1.0/say;
```

Comment: So I have to change P_S[i] to int or what?

Comment: OMG thanks man. You are genious. It worked. I just changed say to float. And it worked. You saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Your loop that calculates P_S is incorrect:

```
P_S[i] = 1/say;
```

Since say is an int, and in your example the value of say is 3, using integer division, 1/say is 1/3 which is 0 (with a remainder of 1).  So all the values of P_S[] are zero, which means all the values of A[] will also be zero, which in turn means sum will be zero.  So when you attempt to calculate final[], you are dividing by zero, hence the NaN.  Perhaps you want:

```
P_S[i] = 1.0/say;
```

By using 1.0, you force in to be a floating-point calculation, so you result will be 0.33333...
There are other inefficiencies in your code as well, byt that is the immediate cause of your error.

Comment: Also, arrays are zero-indexed in c++, so your loops (all of them) should be of the form:  "for(int i = 1; k<say; k++) ".  This isn't an immediate (when you use say=3), but if you were to try say=100, it would fail.

Comment: Also, there is no need to use different loop variable for each loop: they can all be "i".  Also, there do not need to be so many loops; do all your calculations in a single loop.